# How to print void * array with printf when length, element size and format are known?

Tags: arrays, c

I've tried it this way. Then got rubbish in the output and figured out that I'm doing it the wrong way.

```c
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

/*
 * Prints array from the anonymous array pointer.
 *
 * Returns 0 on success.
 * Return -1 on failure.
 */
int print_array(const void *arr, size_t arr_len,
                size_t elem_size, const char *format) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_len; ++i)
        if (printf(format, (char *) arr + i * elem_size) < 0)
            return -1;
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

// Usage example
int main() {
    const int n = 3;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        arr[i] = i;
    print_array(arr, n, sizeof(int), "%d ");
}
```

My code is supposed to work with different possible types. The type is actually deduced somewhere in the beginning of the execution and then this minimal description is used. Such trick nicely works with `scanf` as it takes pointer to an element rather than the element itself.

Such complexity is needed to conform the open-closed priciple and therefore minimise the number of swithes and conditionals in the code. I'm trying to concentrate actual type deducing in one place only.

I guess the same thing as with `scanf` should be possible somehow because `printf` is actually a variadic function which can take any values and parse them during runtime. Abusing "stdarg.h" might help somehow.

Of course I would like to have the solution that is not compiler-specific.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate the problem. Make sure to include appropriate sample data, preferrably as hard-coded data (i.e. simplify the input code away).

Comment: You have not dereferenced `arr` in the function, only computed the address, but `printf()` needs the actual data, not its location.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I can't dereferce `arr` because the type is known in runtime.

Comment: So you can't print it. C doesn't have [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). If you do not know the type, you may print bytes with `char*`, that's about that.

Comment: `type` is required information for what you need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a formatting string, pass a function to print it, allowing the user to do whatever he wants/needs to print the actual data.

```
int print_array(const void *arr, size_t arr_len, size_t elem_size,
       int (*print_elem)(const void *el, void *cookie), // I would add FILE* argument
       void *cookie // allow users to pass additional context if they wanna
) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_len; ++i) {
        if (print_elem((char*)arr + i * elem_size, cookie) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int print_int(const void *el, void *cookie) {
    return printf("%d", *(int*)el);
}

// print and allow users to pass options
int print_int_with_width(const void *el, void *cookie) {
    int width = *(int*)cookie;
    return printf("%*d", width, *(int*)el);
}

int arr[5];
int main() {
    print_array(arr, 5, sizeof(int), print_int, NULL);
    int width = 5;
    print_array(arr, 5, sizeof(int), print_int_with_width, &width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef int (*print_fn)(char*,void*);
    
int print_char  (char *fmt, void *c)   { return printf(fmt, *((char*) c));    }
int print_int   (char *fmt, void *i)   { return printf(fmt, *((int*) i));     }
int print_float (char *fmt, void *f)   { return printf(fmt, *((float*) f));   }
int print_str   (char *fmt, void *str) { return printf(fmt, *((char**) str)); }
// add more types here
    
int print_array (
    void *arr, 
    size_t arr_len, 
    size_t elem_size, 
    char* fmt, 
    print_fn print_elem
){
    for (void *end = arr + arr_len * elem_size; arr < end; arr += elem_size)
        if (print_elem(fmt, arr) < 0)
            return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int print_array(const char *format, const void *arr, size_t arr_len, size_t elem_size, int fp) 
{
    const uint8_t *uarr = arr;
    uint8_t u8;
    uint16_t u16;
    uint32_t u32;
    uint64_t u64;
    float f; double d;
    int result;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_len; ++i)
    {
        switch(elem_size)
        {
            case 1:
                memcpy(&u8, uarr + i, 1); 
                result = printf(format, u8);
                break;
            case 2:
                memcpy(&u16, uarr + i * 2, 2); 
                result = printf(format, u16);
                break;
            case 4:
                if(fp)
                {
                    memcpy(&f, uarr + i * 4, 4); 
                    result = printf(format, f);
                }
                else
                {
                    memcpy(&u32, uarr + i * 4, 4); 
                    result = printf(format, u32);
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                if(fp)
                {
                    memcpy(&d, uarr + i * 8, 8); 
                    result = printf(format, d);
                }
                else
                {
                    memcpy(&u64, uarr + i * 8, 8); 
                    result = printf(format, u64);
                }
                break;
            default:
                result = -1;
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Usage example
int main()
 {
    const int n = 3;
    int arr[n];
    double arrd[3]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
        arrd[i] = 1.1 * i;
    }
    print_array("%d\n", arr, n, sizeof(*arr), 0);
    print_array("%f\n", arrd, n, sizeof(*arrd), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using a macro, you don't need to pass the size of each element:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define print_array(format, array, elems) \
do {                                      \
    for (int ___ = 0; ___ < elems; ___++) \
        printf(format, array[___]);       \
    printf("\n");                         \
} while (0)

int main (void)
{
    char *str[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    print_array("%s ", str, 3);

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    print_array("%d ", arr, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

I use `___` as iterator to prevent shadowing/poluting variable names.

The advantage over a `void *` attached to a callback is that the compiler can detect wrong format specifiers, i.e. passing `"%s "` for the array of `int`s returns:

```
demo.c: In function ‘main’:
demo.c:16:22: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   16 |     print_array(arr, "%s ", 3);
      |                      ^~~~~
demo.c:6:16: note: in definition of macro ‘print_array’
    6 |         printf(format, array[___]);       \
      |                ^~~~~~
demo.c:16:24: note: format string is defined here
   16 |     print_array(arr, "%s ", 3);
```